# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'Adminer'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in cms89\incl\config.php on line 13

Tags: php

I created a login page and then enter a user name and password after that i found this error for usename and password. using a hostname "localhost" username is "Adminer".  what should i do?

Comment: check if connection to db is working?

Comment: Check your credentials. If you're using local server your credentials are most likely `root` `root` for both user and password, or password can be empty (most likely on Windows). Adminer is most likely user created for actual Adminer application itself

Comment: Check your credentials. The error message translates to: "incorrect password, no such user, or user 'Adminer' is not allowed to connect from the hostname 'localhost'"